# Set kendo ui dropdownlist width

Tags: user-interface, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I would like to use a kendo drop-down list, which has a fixed size since is constrained by other fields in the page, but when it shows the drop-down items of the list, the drop-down area should resize to the maximum length of the items. Sort of fixed width for the item displayed, but auto width for the drop down list.
Something like

```
|my choice |     <-- fixed width displayed on the page

|next choice     |
|previous choice |  <-- dropdown area to select another item
|dummy           |
```

Is this possible through CSS or drop-down list properties set through jQuery?

Answer (score 15):

You can set the width of a DropDown List both using a CSS or using a method.

If the id of you `DropDownList` is `my-dropdown` then you should write:

- Using CSS

  ```
  #my-dropdown-list {
      width: auto !important;
  }
  ```

NOTE: We have appended `-list` to the original `id`. The "!important" is important since you want to overwrite original width definition.

- Using a method

  ```
  $("#my-dropdown").data("kendoDropDownList").list.width("auto");
  ```

In addition to use `"auto"` for getting the width automatically adjusted to the text, you can use a fixed width:

```
#my-dropdown-list {
    width: 300px !important;
}
```

or:

```
$("#my-dropdown").data("kendoDropDownList").list.width(300);
```

Answer (score 5):

The above answer didn't work for me. I have a the advantage of knowing that my dropdown is inside of a div.

```
<div class="myDivClass">
   <select id="myDropDown"><option>First</option><option>Second></option></select>
   <!--... other stuff in the div-->
<div>
```

I found that the span has the class k-dropdown so I added the CSS

```
.myDivClass span.k-dropdown {
  width: 300px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to render an extra class on the base element:

```
<input .. class="ExtraLarge ..
```

Which produced:

```
<span style="" class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header ExtraLarge" ..
```

With this ExtraLarge class in place, this worked great in FireFox and Chrome:

```
span.k-dropdown.ExtraLarge
{
    width:400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code to be the template of the kendo dropdownlist:

```
<div class="myDivClass">
<select id="myDropDown"><option>First</option><option>Second></option></select>
<!--... other stuff in the div-->
<div>
```

you will initiate the kendoDropDownList using jQuery as follows:

```
$("#myDropDown").kendoDropDownList().data("kendoDropDownList");
```

Now, to set this controller to take up the full width, what you have to do, is to set the width of the select element to 100%, or whatever is your desire.
e.g.:

```
<select id="myDropDown" style="width: 100%"><option>First</option><option>Second></option></select>
```

OR, is a css file:

```
#myDropDown { width: 100% }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the id of you DropDownList is my-dropdown then you should write:

```
#my-dropdown-list {
    width: auto !important;
    -moz-min-width: 120px;
    -ms-min-width: 120px;
    -o-min-width: 120px;
    -webkit-min-width: 120px;
    min-width: 120px;
    /*max-width: 210px;*/
}
```

Read the explanation below.
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/dropdownlist/how-to/auto-adjust-the-width